# Strange symbol on PSU label

Tags: power-supply, safety, symbol

I have a PSU (wall wart) with a symbol on the label that I don't recognise. I'm curious as to what it means. It's probably some safety symbol of some form, but not one I have ever seen before. I'm sure it's obvious though:

[image]

It's printed on the label with all the other safety symbols, ratings, etc.

Underneath it, I don't know if it's related to the symbol or not, is an ambient temperature rating of `ta=40°C` and an IP rating of `IP20`.

If you're interested, here's the entire label, so you can see it in context (and yes, I know those current ratings are completely wrong - 0.5A in, 0.5A out?!?!):

[image]

Any clues?

Comment: I'll go with switching for 500 Alex....

Comment: You mean to indicate an SMPS? Could be, though I've never seen it on any of the other SMPS wall warts I have...

Comment: That would be my guess ya, have not seen it either.

Comment: Looks like gas discharge tube

Comment: Haven't seen this before and Google reverse image search came up with nothing.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Similar, but no. A GD tube is either two arrows or a plate and a dot.

Comment: The symbol caught my eye because it is so component-like.

Comment: @current ratings: don't have to be wrong, the current in can be 0.5A if the power factor is bad.

Comment: @Arsenal true, but it would have to be something other than your traditional SMPS in there for that to be the case. Maybe it's a capacitive dropper (urgh).  I'll have to tear it down and look.

Comment: By the way, what's the symbol in the lower right corner, the one with the current source in it?

Comment: I don't know that one either, but it looks more like a corporate logo for some foreign (maybe Chinese) safety accreditation (is there such a thing?!)

Comment: _"and yes, I know those current ratings are completely wrong - 0.5A in, 0.5A out?!?!"_ - No they're not. Or at least, they don't have to be. The input current is a _maximum_, which has to account for efficiency, power factor, and (especially) inrush currents. Plus some safety margin. It's a promise from the manufacturer that the input current won't ever exceed 0.5A. Output current is a _minimum_ rating. It's a promise the thing will be able to deliver at least 0.5A to loads that need it. 0.5A on both sounds perfectly plausible.

Comment: Looking through the catalog of IEC symbols the other mystery one is "Safety isolating
transformer, shortcircuit
proof" - 5947 (or I think so, all I have is a preview, and there happens to be a "click here to buy" banner right over that bit).

Comment: Yes, found a better copy: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui#iec:grs:60417:5947

Comment: @marcelm True that, though I've never seen it that way. I have always seen it that the input is quoted as what it would consume with the output at maximum (so 100-240V, 0.7A -> 12V 2A kind of thing)

Comment: @Majenko The numbers you quote would be 70W in vs 24W out, so that is still not accurate according to your interpretation (or the thing would radiate 46W as heat). Everything I said still holds. And because inrush current due to uncharged caps is a very real thing, 0.5A in / 0.5A out sounds as plausible to me as 0.7A in / 2A out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an SMPS symbol from the [IEC 60417](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui#iec:grs:60417:6190) standard. It identifies an

> electronic device incorporating transformer(s) and electronic circuitry(ies), that converts electrical power into single or multiple power outputs.

There's also a similar [symbol](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui#iec:grs:60417:6210) for a linear PSU:

[image: similar symbol with ring and arrow but with added "L" shape]

The PSU must have an internal operating frequency below 500 Hz to be considered linear by the standard.

Comment: That's a rather interesting standard there - have to keep that in mind next time I'm designing a thing.

Answer (score 8):

Power supply unit, switch mode.

ISO Standard
Reference No : 
6190
Registration date : 
2013-10-19

Status : 
Active

Standard :

IEC 60417 — Graphical Symbols for Use on Equipment

Committee :

IEC/SC 3C

ICS :

https://www.iso.org/obp/ui#iec:grs:60417:6190

Comment: Frankly, one thing is missing in the answer: what is that symbol?!

Comment: @GregoryKornblum that's contained in the very first line of the answer.

Comment: Upvote; searching the internet shows https://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_iec60417_DB.pdf, symbol is on page 16.